# Using Youtube API in place of a Youtube Crawler

Tags: youtube, web-crawler, youtube-api

I'm looking to crawl Youtube videos within a given timeframe, e.g. return a list of all (or a fraction of) the videos posted between Jan 14th and Jan 22nd. Does anyone have experience using the youtube data API http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api in this manner, or should I us a crawler instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is another framework called Tubekit to crawl and get videos. I started using that but now am confused if i should continue using it or should use the youtube API to crawl. Any ideas and suggestions ?
Link to TubeKit:
http://www.tubekit.org/

Comment: I briefly reviewed the source code and did not think much of it. PHP for web-crawling is not really the most sensible choice.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used that API, but it seems easy to search videos: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Searching_for_Videos